# How to ingest pixel tracking parameters with DataFlow into BigQuery table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am a beginner in GCP and trying to customize this [serverless pixel tracking architecture](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/images/pixel-tracking-architecture-advanced.svg)
 from the GCP tutorials.

## Goal

Everything shall be built the same except the App Engine and Compute Engine. I don't need them in my example.

My goal is to save the pixel tracking parameters after

**my.tracking-pixel.com/error?[PARAMETERS]**

into BigQuery table using a dedicated error topic over PubSub.

## Status quo

The serverless pixel tracking pipeline up to Logging is up and running. After that, I have created an export sink to publish the data from the pixel tracking into an error topic.

Then, I followed the tutorial guide [from here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faexdxtZGno) to create a DataFlow entity to subscribe to my error topic and ingest the message from the topic into my BigQuery table.

My example table scheme looks like this. It only takes a message of type String.

```
Field name   Type   Mode
msg          STRING NULLABLE
```

Now it is quite easy to publish a message using JSON format

```
{
"msg":"hello world"
}
```

or via the publish message page using google console using the attribute fields. Then my table is correctly updated.

## Ingest attempts

Now I would like to pass the parameters from the tracking and ingest them into my table.

I tried the following syntax without success.

Using key-value mappings.

```
my.tracking-pixel.com/error?msg=hello
```

Using JSON format.

```
my.tracking-pixel.com/error?{"msg":"hello"}
```

## Debugging

In DataFlow, I have seen that my data has been processed while checking the 
input and output collections:

- ConvertMessageToTableRow/JsonToTableRow/JsonToTableRow.out0
- WriteSuccessfulRecords/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/StreamingWrite.out1

Also, I found out that BigQuery is creating an error twin table where it logs the error codes.

This is my payload string

```
{httpRequest={cacheLookup=true, remoteIp=X, requestMethod=GET, requestSize=42, requestUrl=https://my.tracking-pixel.com/error?insertId=4&msg=new1234, responseSize=789, status=200, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36},
insertId=17ktmayg1nsocji, jsonPayload={@type=type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry, statusDetails=response_sent_by_backend},

logName=projects/tracking/logs/requests, 
receiveTimestamp=2019-08-20T08:39:25.712461786Z, 
resource={labels={backend_service_name=, forwarding_rule_name=lbl-collect-pixel-forwarding-rule, project_id=tracking, target_proxy_name=lbl-collect-pixel-target-proxy, url_map_name=lbl-collect-pixel, zone=global},
type=http_load_balancer}, 
severity=INFO, 
spanId=fa0cc3cdcb7e2592, 
timestamp=2019-08-20T08:39:24.922424036Z,
trace=projects/tracking/traces/b335b1acfa78ad5447500cdcda747aa1}
```

This is my error message

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "debugInfo" : "",
    "location" : "logName",
    "message" : "no such field.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "index" : 0
}
```

DataFlow is trying to add the logName attribute in my table which only has a msg attribute.

Now, how can I change the ingestion attempt of my tracking parameters such that DataFlow is correctly parsing it into my desired message format and inserts it into the table?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Cheers,
wiroot

Comment: It seems that the logs provided to dataflow has additional fields.
To confirm this can you please check the message from the actual subscription and make sure that it does not have any additional fields.
If it has additional fields then you can filter those fields by writing your custom pipeline using Beam.

Comment: Also, Stackdriver adds some metadata to the actual log like logName etc which might be the source of these additional fields.

Comment: The payload string I have shared is the data that is published over my pub/sub topic. Thank you, Ankur for pointing towards Beam. It seems to be the right way of creating my own customized pipeline from parsing towards ingesting. I am now following samples on quicklabs.com for my first pipeline attempts.